# string handle in rails makes difficulty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, string

I have my google pie chart code

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ["Work",     50],
          ["Eat",      20],
          ["Commute",  20],
          ["Watch TV", 5],
          ["Sleep",    5]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I need to change it in ruby code.
here in @datas variable i have two field

```
@datas.each do |data|
data.name
data.value
```

It gives two value but i need to write in this order so that my code works like

```
['data.name, data.value]
```

How can i change my ruby code in google api formate? I did but i couldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@dates.map { |d| [d.name, d.value] }
```

EDIT: And the javascript code could be like this:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<%= @dates.map { |d| [d.name, d.value] }.inspect %>)
```

Comment: It comes blank . Can u edit the right answer in my question . I am messed up. Simple comma mistake makes error.

Comment: dont know but again it doesn not display anything. Above code results in such formate [["apple", "10"], ["orange", 20], ["banana", 30], ["grapes", 80], ["papaya", 44]]

Comment: I feel confused. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Yes but it is not workin why i dont know. Look my edited question. You can also try it in your pc . It is not working

Comment: But when i directly put the data (<%= @dates.map { |d| [d.name, d.value] }.inspect %>) which give ([["apple", "10"], ["orange", 20], ["banana", 30], ["grapes", 80], ["papaya", 44]]) inside the  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([["apple", "10"], ["orange", 20], ["banana", 30], ["grapes", 80], ["papaya", 44]]) then it works.